# Generating random characters for a URL in PHP

Tags: php, security, passwords, cryptography

I have answered with my own implementation (below), where I'd appreciate if you could check the maths and logic, but I realise there are other possibilities as well.

---

I'm trying to generate 32 random characters to be used in a registration URL.

The new account is partially created by a member of staff (setting the name/email), and a plain text email is sent to the new user so they can confirm their email address and set their password.

Trying to keep to [A-Za-z0-9] characters, I believe this creates a base 62 system, taking just under 6 bits to store... which is just over 190 bits of entropy? or 190.53428193238?

As this is a security feature, I don't believe `uniqid()` alone is a good idea, as this is based on the current microtime.

And I don't believe using encryption or hashing of the users ID or email address is a good solution either (collisions, low entropy, and presumably secured by a single key).

Comment: If you don't like “+” and “/”, you may replace them with “-” and “_” — that would be just another flavor of Base64, called “base64url”; see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) for more.

Comment: @Anton-Samsonov, good point, although I might still drop the underscore character (or use a full stop) as I've had a couple of instances where a user has seen it as a space (presumably the link was also underlined using a font style that hid that character)... but in principle, is 190 (ish) bits of entropy correct? (not that it really matters, more so checking the maths part).

Answer (score 1):

This works, with the PHP 7.0 random_bytes() function:

```
<?php

function random_key($length, $safe = false) {

    if ($safe !== false) {
        $bad_words = array_map('trim', file('/path/to/bad-words.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));
    } else {
        $bad_words = NULL;
    }

    $j = 0;

    do {

        $bytes = (ceil($length / 4) * 3); // Must be divisible by 3, otherwise base64 encoding introduces padding characters, and the last character biases towards "0 4 8 A E I M Q U Y c g k o s w".
        $bytes = ($bytes * 2); // Get even more, because some characters will be dropped.

        $key = random_bytes($bytes);
        $key = base64_encode($key);
        $key = str_replace(array('0', 'O', 'I', 'l', '/', '+'), '', $key); // Make URL safe (base58), and drop similar looking characters (no substitutions, as we don't want to bias certain characters)
        $key = substr($key, 0, $length);

        if (preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', $key)) {
            exit_with_error('Invalid characters detected in key "' . $key . '"');
        }

        $valid = (strlen($key) == $length);

        if ($bad_words) {
            foreach ($bad_words as $bad_word) {
                if (stripos($key, $bad_word) !== false) {
                    $valid = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if ($valid) {
            return $key;
        }

    } while ($j++ < 10);

    exit_with_error('Cannot generate a safe key after 10 attempts.');

}

?>
```

This code shows how the `base64_encode()` function can biases to certain characters:

```
<?php

$characters = [];

for ($k = 0; $k < 500000; $k++) {

    $key = base64_encode(random_bytes(32)); // 32 bytes results in "=" padding; try changing to 30 to fix.

    foreach (str_split($key) as $c) {
        if (!isset($characters[$c])) {
            $characters[$c] = 0;
        }
        $characters[$c]++;
    }

}

$characters = array_filter($characters, function($value) {
        return ($value > 343750); // ((((33/3)*4)*500000)/64) = 343750, everything else is about ~327000
    });

ksort($characters, SORT_STRING);

print_r($characters);

?>
```

Comment: Don't bother with inventing your very own PRNG out of existing solutions, as chances are high you may receive inferior results as compared to plain `mcrypt_create_iv` or `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`. Moreover, many cryptographic-grade PRNGs already employ strong hashing to improve randomness; are you sure you are not piping their result via an inferior hashing function?

Comment: I must admit I was getting inspiration from Steve Gibson and his SQRL implementation... where he also assumes that a single source could be bad, but that sha256 is a good hashing algorithmn for this... but could be wrong... that and the binary output from these random number generators need to be converted to something URL safe (which is the second part to this problem).

Comment: Just to add to that, the second argument to openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() will tell you if it was a good source, where older systems may be false... and mcrypt_create_iv() can also return not so random data, e.g. Windows systems before PHP 5.3.

Comment: What's a bit annoying with this code is that it can randomly fail if less than `$length` characters are alphanumeric. This is not a problem with 32 char outputs, but becomes a problem as you approach 40 chars. It might be better repeat the process (perhaps with an increased counter as input to the hash) if the output is too short, appending the new data.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, agreed... I should note that the exit() is there for testing purposes, normally I have this attached to a function that causes all kinds of alarms to go off... and yes, if I needed more than 32 characters, I would probably loop, or consider other options.